# Typescript: How to import AutoComplete from enquirer?

Tags: typescript

Attempting to use AutoComplete from enquirer

In https://www.npmjs.com/package/enquirer#autocomplete-prompt they use require

```
const { prompt } = require('enquirer');
```

```
const { AutoComplete } = require('enquirer');
```

While trying the example with 'prompt' converting into import syntax from require syntax the example

```
import { prompt } from 'enquirer';

const app = async () => {
  const response = await prompt({
    type: 'input',
    name: 'username',
    message: 'What is your username?'
  });

  console.log(response);
};

app();
```

Works as expected.

However, when trying to import AutoComplete

```
import { AutoComplete } from 'enquirer';
```

Then the following error arises:

```
Module '"../node_modules/enquirer"' has no exported member 'AutoComplete'.
```

What is the proper way to import AutoComplete from enquirer with Typescript?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible. Enquirer doesn't have complete type definitions ([#135](https://github.com/enquirer/enquirer/issues/135). The only thing you can currently do is to @ts-ignore the line:

```
// @ts-ignore
import { AutoComplete } from 'enquirer';
```